# Ubuntu 16.04 Sound Won't Unmute

Tags: sound

yesterday I installed 16.04 over Windows Vista. It worked perfect, until later I noticed the sound wouldn't unmute. It has a check-mark next to Mute, but it won't let me unmute it. When I go into sound settings, it lets me uncheck the mute button, but still has a little speaker with an x at the top and I can't hear anything.

EDIT: This is my output of `sudo lshw |grep -A9 Audio`

```
 description: Audio device
             product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:fdff4000-fdff7fff
```

Comment: Have you reviewed https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems

Comment: None of the solutions worked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more information.  At the very least provide the output of `sudo lshw |grep -A9 Audio`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I edited it.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a mute button on your keyboard? Does the sound work if you boot from live media?

Comment: are you sure the volume isn't all the way down

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this solution work or not, after hours of debugging I have deleted the pulse audio config settings and boom!!!, it worked.

> Take backup before doing it and do it at your own risk

1. take a backup first

   ```
   cp -r ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse_bak
   ```
2. remove the pulse config

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.config/pulse
   ```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

After hours of frustration and hard work finally found a command that fixed this annoying issue of device not getting unmute, here goes the command

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-x11
```

After this open pulse audio(just search it) and if that opens normally then your issue is fixed.