# All sound input/output dissapeared

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, thinkpad

I had just restarted my computer and logged back in only to find that there was no control over sound whats so ever. All of my input and outputs no longer exist??

[image]

[image]

I do have pulse equalizer installed, though I don't see why this may have caused the issue.

Opening the Guest account I get all my sound controls back including the icon in the top right, same goes for if I log onto my main account into LXDE but not when I log into Unity on my own personal account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own endeavor here:
 [Ubuntu 16.04 Sound Won't Unmute](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814613/ubuntu-16-04-sound-wont-unmute/919974)

In short, this fixed my issue

Make a backup first

```
cp -r ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse_bak
```

remove the pulse config

```
rm -rf ~/.config/pulse
```

Done.